# Thread read video

Tags: android, multithreading

I have two threads one : the first receives a video packet by packet from a server and the second that reads the video.

When the VLC player launches after 5s, only previously received packets are read. The newly received packets are not read...

```
public void test2(){
        Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                DownloadVideo dv = new DownloadVideo();
                dv.connexion();
            }
        });
        t1.start();
        Thread t2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(5000);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, ReadVideo.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        t2.start();
    }
```

Thank you.